# Vue3 create componentes dynamic

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Hello I was testing Vue3, and I came across a situation that I didn't know how to solve for example.

I have an input component that in loop is created with data from an object, all good, but now I want to pass events to it, it is at this point where I don't know how exactly to pass these events to it.
[how to read this list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53UAg.png)

i am trying to create input, using a component, from a json.

**Example**:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-sdkmjl?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.vue

Comment: Please, provide relevant code in the question. It shouldn't be an image. The question should be understandable without navigating to external link which can become unavailable, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "i am trying to create input, using a component, from a json" - JSON doesn't support function values. If this object is really supposed to be JSON, you won't be able to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a specific event handler, it can be specified explicitly:

```
<InputBase v-bind="input" v-model:value="values[input.name]" @input="input.events?.input" />
```

For a map of event handlers, it can be passed to `v-on` directive:

```
<InputBase v-bind="input" v-model:value="values[input.name]" v-on="input.events || {}" />
```